# Lightbox works locally but not when uploaded to the server

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I'm having a problem. I'm using jquery.lightbox-0.5 to display images and everything works fine on my local machine. However, as soon as I upload to my server it doesn't work.

Anyone come across this?

As far as I can tell it's not a capitalisation issue.

I'd be grateful if someone would be able to have a look!

The site is: http://greendeco.ca/gallery.html

Comment: Going to need some more detail. What errors are showing?

Comment: see my answer, it is unable to load jquery due to some permission issues , fix that , it will fix the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

always try to use **firebug** excellent tool which can tell you the error right way.

if you are not using , please start using it.

You are getting the following error

```
$ is not defined
[Break On This Error] $(function() {
```

that means jquery is not included properly ,

this is the error when i try to acess jquery on your page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /jquery-lightbox-0.5/js/jquery.js
on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.0.54 Server at greendeco.ca Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a file permission issue, make sure the file is readable by the apache user (usually www-data)

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

when trying to access the files in the `jquery-lightbox-0.5 folder` :

[view-source:http://greendeco.ca/gallery.html](http://greendeco.ca/gallery.html)

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /jquery-lightbox-0.5/js/jquery.js 
on this server.

Apache/2.0.54 Server at greendeco.ca Port 80
```

which results in a

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

fix your server permissions on that folder

something like:

```
<Directory "/home/domain/www/jquery-lightbox-0.5">
            Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

[more here](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Apache/Setting-Permissions-in-Apache/) 
and restart your server